# Not able to access SSRS using public IP through window azure VM

Tags: azure, reporting-services, window, azure-diagnostics

I am trying to configure `SSRS` on `azure VM`.

it has configured successfully and running fine while accessing from VM's browser with its local server name.

however same thing not working when i am accessing it using public I.P. (e.g. `myvmnam.cloudapp.net/reportserver`).

It asking the username and password (in public ip) but none of username and password are working.

Anyone have idea what i am missing?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to configure an inbound security rule on the Azure portal:
[image]